# DBcontext.Database.Log: executable sql query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use EF6 code first, in  file `Migrations\Configuration.cs` in my Seed method I take entities from third-party services and save these entities in my database.

```
var client = factory.GetByType<T>(); //Get service from ServiceFactory
List<T> entities = client.Search().ResponseContent.List; //Get list of entities of type T from service
entities.ForEach(e => myDbContext.Set<T>().AddOrUpdate(e)); //Fill this entities in my DB
// ...
myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I have sql code that was generated by`myDBcontext.Database.Log = s => myTextWriter(s)` in my Seed method. I would like to execute this SQL query on my testing server (for filling database there) which isn't connected to these third-party services

```
INSERT [dbo].[Segments]([DisplayOrder], [IsActivated], [Name])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Segments]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()


-- @0: '2' (Type = Int32)

-- @1: 'True' (Type = Boolean)

-- @2: 'Industrial' (Type = String, Size = -1)

-- Executing at 23.6.2015 17:10:47 +02:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

Unfortunately this sql code isn't executable. I need something like this:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Commodities]([IsGas], [IsPower], [Name])
VALUES (1, 0, 'Gas')
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Commodities]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
```

Could you give me advise how to generate executable SQL query?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have migrations you can generate a script. Add-Migration xxxxxx then Update-Database -Script. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#script

Comment: Very good question IMO - I spend a lot of time copy/pasting parameter values into parameterized SQL.  I know using SQL Profiler is the probably the correct way to get the actual SQL, but I don't want to install SQL Server (min 4.2 GB) just for this feature!  Maybe a custom DatabaseLogFormatter is the way to go? http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/09/ef6-sql-logging-part-2-changing-the-contentformatting/

Answer (score 0):

EF uses parameters when executing queries and commands to (among others) prevent from SQL Injection attacks. You could try capturing queries/commands using Sql Query Analyzer but you will still not get a "pure" sql - the queries and commands are executed using `sp_executesql`. Maybe instead of capturing commands you could try replicating the data itself - you seem to have access to the database.